# Animation not working when disappearing, but works when appearing

Tags: swift, ios-animations

I'm trying to make a button appear and disappear (animated). When appearing, it animates. But when the button is supposed to disappear it doesn't animate, it just goes away.

anybody any idea why when it appears it animates, but when it disappears it doesn't?

Then button appears when a switch is turned on and disappears when the switch is turned off again.

```swift
if switchesEnabled > 0 {
     UIView.transition(with: button, duration: 0.25, options: .transitionCrossDissolve, animations: {self.button.isHidden = true})
} else {
     UIView.transition(with: button, duration: 0.25, options: .transitionCrossDissolve, animations: {self.button.isHidden = false})
}
```

additionally: the button also disappears when the button itself is pressed and, using exactly the same line of code, in that case it works.

Comment: Where is this code being run?

Comment: in a IBAction func in the view controller file for the view controller the button is in. @HunterMeyer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `UIView.transition` you should use `UIView.animate`.

```
if switchesEnabled > 0 {
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.25, animations: {
        self.button.alpha = 0
    })
} else {
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.25, animations: {
        self.button.alpha = 1
    })
}
```

Setting the alpha to `0` will automatically disable the button.